# Rails Admin not authenticating with Cancancan or Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin, cancancan

I tried this in the config:

```
  ### Popular gems integration
  config.authenticate_with do
    warden.authenticate! scope: :user
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)
```

here, accessing `/admin` gets me stuck in a login loop. I login then get redirected to the login page.

Previously I had tried

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
    #
      user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
      if user.admin?
```

with the CanCanCan authentication in rails admin config. This resulted in user always being nil. Even when I put in

`config.current_user_method(&:current_user)`

How do I fix this to authenticate was an admin?

EDIT: in sessions controller

```
      if user.admin
        redirect_to rails_admin_url
      else
        render json: user
      end
```

and I get stuck in the redirect back to signin.

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: :sessions },
                      path_names: { sign_in: :login }
... then many resources lines
```

EDIT:

Sessions Controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(sign_in_params[:email])
    puts sign_in_params
    if user && user.valid_password?(sign_in_params[:password])
      user.generate_auth_token
      user.save
      if user.admin
        redirect_to rails_admin_url
      else
        render json: user
      end
    else
      render json: { errors: { 'email or password' => ['is invalid'] } }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

Rails admin config, trying this:

```
  ### Popular gems integration
  config.authenticate_with do
    redirect_to merchants_path unless current_user.admin?
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)
```

In ApplicationController:

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user
```

Tried this, current_user is nil.

Comment: Can you show your `config/routes.rb` ? The scope depends on what you defined in `config/routes.rb`

Comment: So, setting current_user didn't work but explicitly setting session[:user_id] in sessions controller then  config.authenticate_with do
    redirect_to merchants_path unless User.find(session[:user_id]).admin?
  end in rails admin config did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THE CONTROLLER LOGIC FOR REDIRECT**

The solution from [Guillermo Siliceo Trueba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412528/guillermo-siliceo-trueba) will not work with your `Users::SessionsController#create` action as you are not calling in [the parent class `create` action](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L23) through the keyword `super`.

The method `create` from the class `Devise::SessionsController` will run `respond_with` in the last line using as `location` the value returned from [`after_sign_in_path_for(resource)`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#after_sign_in_path_for-instance_method)

```
class Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController
  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
end
```

I am using this solution in my [`Users::SessionsController`](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/surfbackend/blob/public/app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb#L8) to handle `html` and `json` requests and you can implement the same.

If the controller receives the `request` with format `.json`, the code between `format.json do .. end` is executed, if the `request` arrives with `format.html` the parent method is called (I cover all your scenarios).

Rails router identifies the request format from the `.json` or `.html` appended at the end of the url (for example GET `https://localhost:3000/users.json`)

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do 
        self.resource = warden.authenticate!(scope: resource_name, recall: "#{controller_path}#new")
        render status: 200, json: resource
      end
      format.html do 
        super
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The `html` request will be routed [to the `super` create action](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L18). You just need to override the method `def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` from the parent as [I am doing in my `ApplicationController`](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/surfbackend/blob/d8b3ace627c3445e175a9c96f99cd62c15aac797/app/controllers/application_controller.rb#L7).

`if resource.admin` then just `return rails_admin_url` from this method and skip the other lines, otherwise follow the normal behavior and call [`super#after_sign_in_path_for(resource)`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/40f02ae69baf7e9b0449aaab2aba0d0e166f77a3/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L215)

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  return rails_admin_url if resource.admin
  super
end
```

**THE ERROR MESSAGES FOR AUTHENTICATION**

`warned.authenticate!` will save inside `self.resource.errors` the error messages. You just need to display the errors on your device using `json_response[:error]` and manipulating the response in your frontend.

I am rendering them in the [`SignInScreen` Component](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/surfnative/blob/master/app/screens/SignInScreen.js#L41)

[image]

**THE TOKEN AUTHENTICATION**

```
user.generate_auth_token
user.save
```

I use the [`simple_token_authentication` for devise](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication) which also allows you to [regenerate the token every time the user signs in](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication#hooks).

You just install the gem and add [`acts_as_token_authenticatable` inside your `user` model](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication#activerecord).

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   acts_as_token_authenticable
end
```

You pass headers `X-User-Email` and `X-User-Token` with the corresponding values as explained [in their guide](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication#activerecord).

Other [alternatives to `simple_token_authentication`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Simple-Token-Authentication-Example)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to define the after_sign_in_path_for method on the ApplicationController

By default, it first tries to find a valid resource_return_to key in the session, then it fallbacks to resource_root_path, otherwise it uses the root path. For a user scope, you can define the default url in the following way:

```rb
get '/users' => 'users#index', as: :user_root # creates user_root_path

namespace :user do
  root 'users#index' # creates user_root_path
end
```

If the resource root path is not defined, root_path is used. However, if this default is not enough, you can customize it, for example:

```rb
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  stored_location_for(resource) ||
    if resource.is_a?(User) && resource.can_publish?
      publisher_url
    else
      super
    end
end
```

Comment: Hey, I found the issue was in my Sessions controller, it wasjust returning JSON. I tried doing == please see edit